# CreateProcess and redirecting output

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd

There are 2 apps.

`AppCMD` is a command line app and `AppMAIN` starts `AppCMD` with some command line args.
Unfortunately `AppMAIN` does not seem to handle the output off `AppCMD` very well and something is going wrong.

I'd like to log the calls to `AppCMD` and its output to see what is going on.

In order to do so I want to replace `AppCMD` with another binary `AppWRAP` that forwards the calls to a renamed `AppCMD` and logs it's output.
`AppWRAP` should act like a transparent Man-In-The-Middle.

For testing purposes I wrote a simple `AppCMD` that just outputs it's command line args:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "#### Hello, I'm the test binary that wants to be wrapped." << endl;

    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "#### There where no command line arguments." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "#### These are my command line arguments:";
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) cout << " " << argv[i];
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "#### That's pretty much everything I do ... yet ;)" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I followed [MSDN: Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) to implement `AppWrap` but I got stuck since it does not return and I cant figure out why:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;


const string TARGET_BINARY("TestBinary.exe");
const size_t BUFFSIZE = 4096;

HANDLE in_read        = 0;
HANDLE in_write       = 0;
HANDLE out_read       = 0;
HANDLE out_write      = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stringstream call;

    cout << "Hello, I'm BinTheMiddle." << endl;

//-------------------------- CREATE COMMAND LINE CALL --------------------------

    call << TARGET_BINARY;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        call << " " << argv[i];
    }

    cout << "Attempting to call '" << call.str() << "'" << endl;

//------------------------------ ARRANGE IO PIPES ------------------------------

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES security;
    security.nLength              = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    security.bInheritHandle       = NULL;
    security.bInheritHandle       = TRUE;
    security.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&out_read, &out_write, &security, 0)) {
        cout << "Error: StdoutRd CreatePipe" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(out_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        cout << "Stdout SetHandleInformation" << endl;
        return -2;
    }
    if (!CreatePipe(&in_read, &in_write, &security, 0)) {
        cout << "Stdin CreatePipe" << endl;
        return -3;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(in_write, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        cout << "Stdin SetHandleInformation" << endl;
        return -4;
    }
//------------------------------ START TARGET APP ------------------------------

    STARTUPINFO         start;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION proc;

    ZeroMemory(&start, sizeof(start));
    start.cb         = sizeof(start);
    start.hStdError  = out_write;
    start.hStdOutput = out_write;
    start.hStdInput  = in_read;
    start.dwFlags    |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    ZeroMemory(&proc, sizeof(proc));

    // Start the child process.
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR) call.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE,
                       0, NULL, NULL, &start, &proc))
    {
        cout << "CreateProcess failed (" << GetLastError() << ")" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(proc.hProcess, INFINITE);
    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle(proc.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(proc.hThread);

//----------------------------------- OUTPUT -----------------------------------

    DWORD dwRead;
    CHAR  chBuf[127];

    while (ReadFile(out_read, chBuf, 127, &dwRead, NULL)) {
        cout << "Wrapped: " << chBuf << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like it is waiting for `ReadFile` to return. Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

I call the binary this way:

```
> shell_cmd_wrapper.exe param1 param2
```

This is the console output but the binary does not return.

```
Hello, I'm BinTheMiddle.
Attempting to call 'TestBinary.exe param1 param2'
Wrapped:#### Hello, I'm the test binary that wants to be wrapped.
#### These are my command line arguments: param1 param2
#### That'sD
Wrapped: pretty much everything I do ... yet ;)
s to be wrapped.
#### These are my command line arguments: param1 param2
#### That'sD
```

(Please ignore that I don't clear the buffer)

Comment: You probably need to use `PeekNamedPipe` before reading to determine size of available data.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you. I called `CloseHandle(out_write); CloseHandle(in_read);` And It seems to do what It should :) I have plans to accept an answer when you have plans to write one.

Comment: On a side note, after `ReadFile()` you should add a null-terminator to `chBuf` because `ReadFile` doesn't do that. You may just be lucky that `chBuf` was initially filled with zeros, but it could be random data aswell so `cout` would write garbage after the actual string or even crash.

Comment: `CHAR chBuf[127+1]; while (ReadFile(out_read, chBuf, 127, &dwRead, NULL)) { chBuf[dwRead] = 0; cout << "Wrapped: " << chBuf << endl; }` - Note that I also increased buffer size by 1 to make room for null terminator.

Comment: @zett42: or, you can use [`cout.write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) instead of `cout <<`, then you don't need to use a null terminator at all: `cout << "Wrapped: "; cout.write(chBuf, dwRead); cout << endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the `out_write` and `in_read` handles after calling `CreateProcess`. Otherwise `ReadFile` on `out_read` will block when the pipe is empty because there's still a potential writer even after the child has exited -- the `out_write` handle in the current process.

Also, as noted by Harry Johnston in a comment, waiting for the process to exit before reading from the pipe can potentially cause a deadlock. The child will block on `WriteFile` if the pipe fills up.

Comment: when the **last** handle to pipe end is closed - another pipe end will be disconnected. `ReadFile` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastErro`r returns `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`. OP have 2 handles to pipe end - in child and parent process. when child exit - handles in it is closed, but still exist active handle in child. so another end not disconnected and `ReadFile` not return. close additional handle in parent fix this problem. also we can create 1 pipe paire instead of 2.

Comment: @RbMm, the OP ignores the error from `ReadFile`, which will be `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` when the child has exited, assuming the handle `out_write` handle was closed. It would be better to check this case so as to not silently ignore other errors. I don't know why you say only 1 pipe is needed, if that's what you mean by a "pipe paire". The OP is setting the standard input as well. We don't see code where that's being used, but it will be needed to drive the input of AppCMD. Then deadlocking is a problem again, which is most easily resolved with another thread.

Comment: `ReadFile` not return because pipe end not disconnected when child exit - still exist handle for this end in parent process. when we close it - this fix problem. and about 1 pair - i mean that enough create only 2 handles - `CreateNamedPipe` (parent handle) + `CreateFile` (copy it to child and close in parent). this is enough for work. bot handles must have read/write access. but almost all used 2 pair (4 handles)

Comment: about well known deadlocks here - i always use only asynchronous io. and in this no any deadlocks, we not depend from read/write order between parent and child. and 1 pair (1 handle in paren + 1 in child) here enough

Comment: @RbMm, `CreatePipe` calls `NtCreateNamedPipe` and `NtOpenFile` for you. If you do it yourself, you still have to close your copy of the inherited or duplicated handle. But by calling `CreateNamedPipe` and `CreateFile` manually you have the option to use asynchronous I/O.

Comment: yes, by calling CreateNamedPipe and CreateFile manually you have the option to use asynchronous I/O. + `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` (+just set correct inheritance - for not call `SetHandleInformation`) -all this is allow have one pipe pair instead 2 pair (4 handles). but of course handle which we duplicate to child need close in parent